# when can a page source has contents but not displayed on web page?

Tags: php, browser, view-source

I'm developing a fb web app. I have got a situation in which view-source of web page shows contents but not displayed on actual page. But when I refresh the page it displays. Can anyone explain why it happens?

I've used may redirections before getting into that page.

Answer (score 0):

Disable all the redirection and see what's happening. If you're using cookies to define how the page redirects, please remember that you can't read cookies just after their creation in the same page.